# Hide parent background in space that child occupies

Tags: html, css

I have a background image and a menu bar. The menu bar is black. When I hover on a menu button, I'd like to make it transparent so that the background image is visible but the menu bar's black background gets in the way.

How could I mask out the parent background under a child element?

```css
body {
  background-color:green;
  background:url("https://images.pexels.com/photos/82256/pexels-photo-82256.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940");
  background-size:cover;
}

.parent, .child {
  display:inline-block;
}

.parent {
  background:red;
}

.child {
  background:yellow;
}

.child:hover {
  background:transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  I'm the parent: 
  <div class="child">
    Child
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    Child
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    Child
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    Child
  </div>
</div>
```

When a `.child` is hovered over, it should have the background (in this case it's a portion of an image) of the superparent (in this case `<body>`).

Comment: @j08691 added an example and will do in the future thanks. What's so bad about my question that nobody should upvote it though?

Comment: Read [ask] for why. Your question also had no code, and still doesn't. Your question should contain all the code necessary to troubleshoot the issue in a [mcve]; it shouldn't exist on a third-party site like jsFiddle since So has stack snippets. Plus, links to offsite resource can rot, be blocked, etc.

Comment: @j08691 oh okay. Better?

Comment: You're getting there. Your question mentions background images but your example doesn't have any images. If you don't have your own to link to there are free image placeholder services you can use.

Comment: @j08691 I guess it helps understand why I'd want to do this- added a royalty free image from Pexels

Comment: You can't do that, so you need to figure another way to make the visible part of the parent red. An option could  be a pseudo for the parent text and a side border on the child elements

Answer (score 0):

It will depend on your actual requirements but you can not place a background color on the `ul` but it is possible to place a background color on a couple of pseudo-elements which will mimic the same behaviour.

```css
body {
  background-color: green;
  background-size: cover;
}

.parent {
  display: flex;
}

.parent::before,
.parent::after {
  content: "";
  background: black;
  flex: 1;
}

.child {
  display: flex;
  padding: 1em;
}

.child {
  background: yellow;
}

.child:hover {
  background: transparent;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">

  <div class="child">
    Child
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    Child
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    Child
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    Child
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -3):

```css
.menuBar {  background-color: #000;color:white;}

.menuBar:hover {background-color:transparent;color:black;}
```

```html
<html>

<span class ="menuBar">Menu bar items</span>


</html>
```